# Find operator in JavaScript with SQL

Tags: javascript, sql, typescript

I need help to build a query for an SQL database. My 'alocatedAgent' has an id, and I need to return every service of the id passed and the services that alocatedAgent.id is null. I have this code:

```
findByUserId = async (
    alocatedAgent: User,
    transactionEntityManager?: EntityManager
  ): Promise<IBSService[]> => {

    const slaStatus = [
      SLAStatus.Arquivado,
      SLAStatus.Rejeitado,
      SLAStatus.Cancelado,
    ];

    const newWhere = {
      alocatedAgent,
      slaStatus: Not(In(slaStatus)),
    };

    const data = await this.bsServiceRepository.findAll(
      [newWhere],
      transactionEntityManager,
    );

    return data.map((bsService) => ({
      ...bsService,
      logs: bsService.logs.sort(
        (a, b) => b.createAt.getTime() - a.createAt.getTime()
      ),
  }));
};
```

Here what I tried so far and didn't work:

```
alocatedAgent: alocatedAgent.id || alocatedAgent.id IsNull()
//
alocatedAgent: In([alocatedAgent.id, null])
```

I think I need to put an *or* in this, but I really don't know how.

Comment: what kind of ORM do you use?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see any SQL in your question.